# how to solve nested if issue

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I am new to UNIX ... I am trying to write a bash script that takes two integers from the user and prints out the even numbers between these two numbers using an if condition. I am stuck on the nested if "an unexpected token near else" error message appears.  I do not know what the error is about. Any help?

This is what I have done so far:

```
echo plz enter first number
read n1
echo plz enter second  number
read n2
start=$n1
end=$n2
if [ start < end ] then 
    for (c=start;c<=end;c++)
    do

        if [ $((c % 2 )) -eq 0 ]; then
            echo $c
        fi
    done
else
    echo "not bigger"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would recommend a different approach:

```
((start % 2)) && ((start = 1 + start))
while ((start < end))
do
  echo ${start}
  (( start += 2))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried like this:-

```
echo "Enter first number"
read first
echo "Enter second number"
read second
start=$first

endLine=$second
while [ $start -le $endLine ]
do
 if [ $((start % 2 )) -eq 0 ]
 then
 echo $start "is an even number"
#else
# echo $start "is an odd number"
fi
start=`expr $start + 1`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert either a semicolon or a newline before the first "`then`":

```
if [ start < end ] ; then
                   ^
```